# update cdata dynamically

Tags: php, magento-1, xml

I am creating copy of xml file and try to change local.xml file database name dynamically but CData is not getting proper.

my code is below,

```
 $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
 $xml->formatOutput = true; 
 $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
 $xml->load('local.xml');
 $xpath = new DOMXpath($xml);
 $element = $xml->getElementsByTagName('dbname')[0];  
 $element->nodeValue = '<![CDATA['test']]>'; 
 $xml->save($new_file);
```

But output is `<dbname>&lt;![CDATA[test instance]]&gt;</dbname>`.

I need output with `<dbname><![CDATA[test instance]]></dbname>`.

Can any one have solution how i can achieve this.

Comment: You can try `createCDATASection('test')`.

Comment: can you please give me example or link ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not really related to Magento.

Comment: Added example ...you can also try  `replaceChild()` - see http://php.net/manual/de/domnode.replacechild.php

Answer (score 1):

You can try this - it clears current value and adds your CDATA:

```
$element = $xml->getElementsByTagName('dbname')->item(0);
$element->nodeValue = '';
$element->appendChild($xml->createCDATASection('test'));
```